# Decrement with value don't work in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have this simple problem but i don't know what is wrong in it.
I want to decrement a value but it doesn't seem to work.
The result value is still 3 every time i click the button what i want is to decrement .

```
int _qty = 0;
onPressed: (){
 setState(() {
    _qty = loadCartData[index]['d_id']; // value from database with 4
    _qty--;
    });
   print(_qty);
 },
```

Comment: If you keep re-reading the value from the `loadCartData` and never change what's stored in `loadCartData`, then you'll always end up with the same value.

Comment: thank you guys i figured it out , thank you @jamesdlin for in lighting my mind